# why document retrieval request with default routing goes to any node in elastic cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was reading the elastic documentation and was on the following [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/distrib-read.html).

In point 1 and 2, it says "request goes to Node 1. Node 1 finds that document belongs to Node 0."

Since, default routing is done on the _id of document, so why not the request itself lands on Node 0 (based on default routing)? 
Why the request goes to Node  1 (which has to find out that the document is on Node 0)?

It would have been more efficient if request directly lands on the node where docuemnt belongs to, and then this node should have done load balancing (move request to replica shards if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You are right. On first observation there is a useless rerouting happening. However, in order to prevent hot spots, by default the request is routed to any of the three shards in a round robin fashion.

Imagine you are only ever connecting to one of your cluster nodes with that client, then you would always only query that one node, potentially underutilizing the other nodes. This is why it is round robin by default.

You can however change the behaviour by setting the [preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-preference.html) parameter to `_local`